# Sample username-signup-or-signin policy prompting for email address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm attempting to use the sample custom policy [username-signup-or-signin](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin). However, without any changes on my part, it is prompting for the email address on the sign-in screen instead of the username. You can see this by using the [live demo link](https://b2clivedemo.b2clogin.com/b2clivedemo.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Demo_SUSI_Username/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=cfaf887b-a9db-4b44-ac47-5efff4e2902c&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login) in GitHub.

I've attempted to look through the XML of the extension policy but can't figure out how to have it ask for the username instead of the email address. For example, the extension policy includes the following:

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
```

It seems that would cause B2C to prompt for the username instead of email.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the placeholder text to ‘please enter your username’.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thank you very much for the very quick response (on this and my other question). Does B2C always accept either an email or username for sign-in (and it is just the label that tells the user which is preferred)?

Comment: Not at all, hence the sample policy. Placeholder is just for aesthetics. If you didnt follow the link, your policy would still be functional.